# Best strategy for connecting two objects

Tags: java, android, class, object

I know how to implement both of the features below, but I was wondering which one would be superior in terms of memory/battery/efficiency/etc. or if there is a different method that I did not mention below.

I've simplified it below:

I have 2 classes: 1) Users and 2) Characters

Both classes have an unique id (userID and charID respectively).

Method1:

```
The User class accepts a string called charID. 
(which would be used to pull from the Character object)
```

Method2:

```
The User class accepts a Character Object called character.
(So this would already include the entire object within itself)
```

Is one better practice than the other? Or should I be looking at a different method instead?

The main goal here is to connect 2 objects together without having ALL of the key-values of one object written into the first object.

Looking forward to your thoughts!
Thanks!

Comment: I believe it would be fine with either one. That's why I'm asking if one is better practice or better efficiency-wise. If I give it a charID, then when I need to access the character object I will have to find the object by charID.

Comment: You don't say anything about what "pull from" means.  Are you getting these things from a database?  Is this the in-memory representation of the data graph?  It makes a difference...

Comment: Sorry, I will have these stored on Firebase Database. and then pulling them from there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the method 2 is much better because you keep a memory reference of the character object instead of having a simple String that will be used and spend much more processing power to access the character object.

In method 2, your User objects will have an attribute that works like a pointer, that will point to a Character object (in memory), this way you can access the full object without having to write all of its atributes in the User class.